# What threshold to move from SEP to Solo401k?

Tags: united-states, retirement, self-employment, solo-401k

I'm self employed. Currently planning to fund a SEP for 2010. At what threshold do I need to switch to a Solo401k?

(I'm in the SEP because (a) it's easy and (b) it's cheap -- no fees. Solo401k looked like an expensive hassle last year.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this article](http://www.kiplinger.com/columns/ask/archive/2007/q0801.htm) explains it pretty well:

> Contributions to a SEP are limited to
>   20% of your business  income (which is
>   business income minus half of your
>   self-employment tax), up to a maximum
>   of $45,000. With a solo 401(k), on the
>   other hand, you can contribute up to
>   $15,500 plus 20% of your business
>   income (defined the same way as
>   above), with a maximum contribution of
>   $45,000 in 2007. You can make an extra
>   $5,000 catch-up contribution if you're
>   50 or older

Comment: Then if I understand it right, if business income is $77500 then SEP max is $15500 and solo401k max is $31000. At $225k income, SEP max is $45000 and solo401k max is $45000.

Comment: From that article, the solo 401k seems like it's not worth it.

Comment: I believe in 2010 it's 25%